# select all id's and insert missing data

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a database where i store some values with a auto generated index key. I also have a n:m mapping table like this:

```
create table data(id int not null identity(1,1), col1 int not null, col2 varchar(256) not null);
create table otherdata(id int not null identity(1.1), value varchar(256) not null);
create table data_map(dataid int not null, otherdataid int not null);
```

every day the `data` table needs to be updated with a list of new values, where a lot of them are already present but needs to be inserted into the `data_map` (the key in `otherdata` is then generated, so in this table the data is always new).

one way of doing it would be to first try to insert all values, then select the generated id, then insert into `data_map`:

```
mydata = [] # list of tuples
cursor.executemany("if not exists (select * from data where col1 = %d and col2 = %d) insert into data (col1, col2) values (%d, %d)", mydata);

# now select the id's
# [...]
```

but that obviously is quite bad because i need to select all things without using the key and also i need to do the check without using the key, so i need indexed data first, otherwise everything is very slow.

my next approach was to use a hashfunction (like md5 or crc64) to generate my own hash over col1 and col2, to be able to insert all values without using a select and be able to use the indexed key when inserting missing values.

can this be optimized or is it the best thing i could do?
the amout of lines is >500k per change, where maybe ~20-50% will be already in the database.
timing wise it looks like that calculating the hashes is much faster than inserting data into the database.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I concern, you use mysql.connector. If it is, when you run cursor.execute() you should not use %d types. Everything should be just %s and connector will do this job about type conversions

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's question. While true, it should have been a comment.

Comment: I would love to, but I still have no reputatuion to make a comments in the other forks.

Comment: ok well, this is afaik just the consens on a mailing list and not strictly defined somewhere in a PEP or so. the PEP just defines that you can use some kind of formatter string.